# mailer does not work on prod with the same settings as on dev

Tags: symfony, email

Basically after changing from Dev to Prod on Symfony, the mailer stopped sending mails to given email.

Posting few settings from my Symfony:
parameters:

```
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_port: 465 
    mailer_host: myhost
    mailer_user: mylogin
    mailer_password: mypw
```

config:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    port: '%mailer_port%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
    logging: true
# delivery_addresses: ['']
```

It looks correctly for me. The website uses SSL if that matters. Is there anything to change/edit? Do you need any other code to assist me with?

Comment: is the commented out delivery_adress the problem?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough info here. The swiftmailer config looks fine. What version of Symfony are you using? Depending on the version there's different places to look for overrides (ex. in symfony 4 you'd look in `config/packages/dev` or `config/packages/prod` to find overrides on (swift)mailer. In Symfony 3 look for `config_dev` or `config_prod.yml`. Also check your env (or parameters) variables to make sure the host/port/user/password are correct. This could eventually also be a firewall issue or some such.